# checking for existence of a stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

Does any body know why the following SQL returns a syntax error (Incorrect syntax near 'IF') in SQL Server 2012?

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS MyStoredProcedure;
```

I know I can use the following instead:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.procedures 
      WHERE Name = 'MyStoredProcedure')
```

But I wonder why the first one produces the error.

Thanks!

Comment: Simply put, the first bit of tsql doesn't follow the [syntax for dropping procedures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174969(v=sql.110).aspx).

Comment: Man, I need more coffee... I totally missed that.

Comment: Thanks @DMason! I found that syntax from here: [link] (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/drop-procedure.html)   Also I saw it in  some older codes from the company that I am working. My guess is that maybe a different version of SQL supports it.

Comment: That documentation is for MySql, not MS SQL Server. ..SQL Server has never had a `drop if exists` syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.procedures 
      WHERE Name = 'MyStoredProcedure')
      print 'yes'
      -- drop procedure mystoredprocedure
```

You must have something else in your query window that's throwing the error, or you're running things in the wrong order.

For what it's worth, this is my "go to" for dropping/building procedures before I `CREATE PROCEDURE`... all my saved proc scripts have this.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.uspSomeProcName') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP PROCEDURE dbo.uspSomeProcName
    IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.uspSomeProcName') IS NOT NULL
        PRINT '<<< FAILED DROPPING PROCEDURE dbo.uspSomeProcName>>>'
    ELSE
        PRINT '<<< DROPPED PROCEDURE dbo.uspSomeProcName>>>'
END
```

Comment: Have you ever seen a case where you get the message "<<< FAILED DROPPING.."?  I would think that any error in the DROP statement would cancel the batch...you should use TRY / CATCH instead..

Comment: Yes, I've seen it... but only when it doesn't exist... so then I truck along and build anew.

Comment: If the proc doesn't exist, then it won't go into the first BEGIN to get to the DROP in the first place...or am I missing something?..

Comment: Thanks @JiggsJedi! @srutzky You are right. If the procedure does not exist, the code does not get to the drop part. The OBJECT_ID('dbo.uspSomeProcName') is checked again to make sure that the Drop worked.